# Rotted wood behind the tile in my shower stall - anything I can do short of tearing out the wall?

Tags: wood, shower, tile, mold, rot

[image]

Pulled off the tile in my shower stall window and found water damage underneath. Don’t know how extensive it is yet.

I know I eventually need to take out the whole wall and let it air out. Thing is, I’m heading out of town for a few weeks and won’t have the time/money to fix this until I’m back. In the immediate term, is there anything I can do to help mitigate the wood rot before I close it back up?

I already scraped out as much of the rotted wood as I could and sprayed mold killer down there. I have fans going to help dry it out. TIA for any advice!

Comment: Beware of spraying mold killer into an enclosed space, the water part can linger much longer than the mold killer part, thereby encouraging the growth of mold.

Comment: Will need to find out where the water is coming from.  Shower should be easy, outside or the roof gets more interesting.

Comment: You're heading out of town. Will the shower be used while you're gone? If not, then just leave it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced to go along with the intense fervor that I frequently see around household mold. If the mold isn't blooming up through the grout lines lower on that wall, then my instinct is to fix the leak source(s), dry out the wall cavities, and then close up the wall again.

Drying out the wall cavities might not be so easy if you even bother gaining access to them (the insulation sounds painful to deal with). Without an exit for the air down low, a fan at the top is similar to blowing into a Coke bottle. I would buy a little squirrel cage blower to push air down to the cavity bottoms. Or just not bother peaking in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Your temporary fix can be plastic sheeting and tape.  It might not last a few weeks so demonstrate to your family how to repair/replace it.  Then you can deal with this properly when you're back.   Get a borescope to better see how extensive the damage is.  Depending on your exterior finish it might be easier to gain access through the outside wall than through tiles.

If there was a small leak through the window sill into the wood, the damage may be limited to what you see.  Don't despair yet.